# Beanstalk Cronjobs using django-cron

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Im trying to get cronjobs running on my elasticbeanstalk ec2 instance using django-cron.

I created a cronjob.cron:

```
*/5 * * * * root /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3 /opt/python/current/app/manage.py runcrons >> /var/log/cronjobs.log
```

and added the file using commands:

```
container_commands:
  06_runcrons:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/cronjobs.cron > /etc/cron.d/djangocrons && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/djangocrons"
    leader_only: true
```

The cron seems to run but nothing gets printed into my /var/log/cronjobs.log (Which it should, every 5mins).

I cannot test the script on the ec2 instance manually, because my environment variables I added using   `aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:` are neither present with the ec2-user or root. Where do those environment variables get written to? Are they only present during the deploy?
The server itself works fine, so my db environment variables work.

Do I need to use another user for my cronjobs? How can I solve this?

Edit:
Removing the user like:

```
*/5 * * * * /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3 /opt/python/current/app/manage.py runcrons >> /var/log/cronjobs.log
```

results in

```
(CRON) bad username (/etc/cron.d/djangocrons)
```

in my /var/log/cron

Comment: Did you try without root (aka `*/5 * * * * /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3 /opt/python/current/app/manage.py runcrons >> /var/log/cronjobs.log`)?

Comment: updated my question with the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding the file that sources the env variables in /opt/python/current/env

```
*/5 * * * * root source /opt/python/current/env && /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3 /opt/python/current/app/manage.py runcrons >> /var/log/cronjobs.log
```